# Access feature module routes config data from app module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Is there any way to access the feature module routing config from routing config from the app. component

I have one feature module which is lazy loaded. I want to access feature module routing data on my `app.module` to highlight my side nav bar(KendoUI Drawer) menu item based on the URL's child path. for example if past the `http://localhost:4200/parent/child-component-name` to the browser navigation user should see the `child-component-name` selected in the side nav bar.

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

------------ app.routing.module.ts --------------

```
const parentRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'parent',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'parent',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/parent/parent.module').then(
        (m) => m.parent
      ),
  },
];
```

------------ child.routing.module.ts --------------

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
     path: '',
     component:ParentViewComponent,
     children:[
       {
         path:'',
         component: FirstChildComponent,
       },
       {
         path: 'second',
         component: SecondChildComponent,
       },
       {
         path: 'third',
         component: ThirdChildComponent,
       },
     }
   ]
```

in my app.component.ts I was able to access the parent route data using `this.router.config` but only provides two routes in `app.routing.module.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the route config after modifying it for the feature module that you are lazy loading.

In order to access the route config of the feature module (in your case child routing module),you can try accessing _loadedRoutes and modify as per your need and reset overall routeconfig.

```
Const newConfig=this.router.config.map(routeConfig=>{
if(routeConfig.path==='parent')
{
    // Here you can find the route configs for lazy loaded module for path 'parent'
    console.log(outeConfig._loadedRoutes)

    // Do the modifications here

}

return routeConfig

})

this.router.resetConfig(newConfig)


// ie; this.routee.config[<indexOfLazyloadedModule>]._loadedRoutes
```